Dockerfile to automatically build all csproj files in subfolders
I'm building an application with plugin architecture, so the source can contain many different plugins (but ordered in the same folder) like this:
src
  - Dockerfile
  - mainProject
    - mainProject.csproj
    - program.cs
  - plugins
    - plugin1
      - plugin1.csproj
      - plugin1.cs
    - plugin2
      - plugin2.csproj
      - plugin2.cs

mainProject will not have a reference to the plugin projects, so running the following command in Dockerfile will publish the main project to /app/publish and will not include the plugins:
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish "mainProject/mainProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

Now I want to publish each plugin to /app/publish/plugins so that plugin1 is published to /app/publish/plugins/plugin1 and similar for plugin2.
To reduce the maintenance needs I don't want to have to update the Dockerfile every time a new plugin is created, so I would like to do this automatically.
I'm not very familiar with shell scripts. What I have is the follwing, which prints the correct command, but I don't know how to execute it properly, or if there is a better way.
find . -type f -name '*.csproj' -printf "dotnet publish %p -c Release -o /app/publish/plugins/%h\n"
How can I automatically build all .csproj files in subfolders, and publish them to their own folder, from a Dockerfile

I suppose find -exec should do the trick
find ./plugins/ -type f -name '*.csproj' -exec dotnet publish {} -c Release -o /app/publish/plugins \;

Hope it helps!

The issue with this is that all the plugins would be published to the same directory, not one directory per plugin.

Have you tried piping your original find -printf into bash or sh? It should work.
find ... -printf "..." | bash

I had already tried piping it like that without success, but, of course, when I now tried again it worked just as I expected the first time. Thanks for your virtual magic touch :)

Feel free to update your answer and I'll mark it as answered :)
